# How to rotate an image on touch using RotateToAction in libGDX?

Tags: libgdx

[image]

I want to rotate my image on touch but it never applies action, I'm using RotateToAction to achieve this.

```
class actorCark extends Actor
{
    Texture texture;
    Sprite sprite;
    Global g;
    GetActorByName a;
    public actorCark()
    {
        ses=new sesler();
        g=new Global();
        a=new GetActorByName();
        sr=new soruSor();
        texture=new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("images/carkifelek.png"));
        sprite=new Sprite(texture);
        setBounds(Global.screen_width / 2 - Global.screen_height * 0.9F * sprite.getTexture().getWidth() / sprite.getTexture().getHeight() / 2, Global.screen_height / 2 - Global.screen_height * 0.9F / 2, Global.screen_height * 0.9F * sprite.getTexture().getWidth() / sprite.getTexture().getHeight(), Global.screen_height * 0.9F);
        setTouchable(Touchable.enabled);
        addListener(new InputListener() {
            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int buttons) {
                clearActions();
                RotateToAction rotateToAction=new RotateToAction();
                rotateToAction.setRotation(360);
                rotateToAction.setDuration(2);
                addAction(rotateToAction);
                dondur();
                sesler.donmeS.play();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void act(float delta) {
        super.act(delta);
    }
    public void draw(Batch batch, float alpha)
    {
        sprite.getTexture().setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.Linear, Texture.TextureFilter.Linear);
        sprite.setBounds(Global.screen_width / 2 - Global.screen_height * 0.9F * sprite.getTexture().getWidth() / sprite.getTexture().getHeight() / 2, Global.screen_height / 2 - Global.screen_height * 0.9F / 2, Global.screen_height * 0.9F * sprite.getTexture().getWidth() / sprite.getTexture().getHeight(), Global.screen_height * 0.9F);
        sprite.setOrigin(sprite.getWidth() / 2, sprite.getHeight() / 2);
        sprite.draw(batch);
    }
}
```

Comment: do you call stage.act() in your main game loop?

Comment: stage2.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()); I am sure I do call it

Comment: other cand of actions like moveToAction are working butr only rotate action doesnt works

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are rotating your actor with the rotateTo action, but your sprite, which is doing the actual drawing, knows nothing about the actor's rotation. Try `sprite.setRotation(this.getRotation())` in your draw() code.

Comment: I do yes it works but as you can see in the image I added to my post, I need to use some animation to make wheel rotate